# Graphing a function?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

[image]

How can you have a function on the $x$ and $y$ axis?

I thought graphing functions worked like this: You have a variable on one of the axis, and a function of the variable on the other axis. How can you graph two independent functions of a  common variable on the same graph?

Answer (score 1):

You can also have parametric function $(x(t),y(t))$. For instance, the circle is expressed as the following:
$$
x(t)=\rho\cos(t),
$$
$$
y(t)=\rho\sin(t),
$$
$$
t\in[0,2\pi].
$$
And this figure is two dimensional.

This is one other way to interpret the "classical" way to plot a graph, as you wrote in your question.